# using a new component with react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering, react-component

I have created a LogOut button component over my react app.

This is how it looks like:

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
 import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

 export class LogOutButton extends Component {
  static contextTypes = {
    store: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  };

  handleClick = () => {
    this.context.store.dispatch();
  };

  render() {
    return <button type="button" onClick={this.handleClick}>Logout</button>;
  }
}
```

All I want to do is to use this component inside index.js such that when the user clicks the LogOut button, he will be directed to www.google.com.

1. How should I change the LogOutButton component so it will redirect the user to google.com ?
2. How should I use the component inside index.js ?

This is my index.js:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css';
import './index.css';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { LogOutButton } from './components/LogOutButton.js';

class Home extends React.Component {
  displayName = Home.name;

  state = {
    result: 0,
    val1: 0,
    val2: 0,
  };

  handleChangeOne = event => {
    this.setState({ val1: event.target.value });
  };

  handleChangeTwo = event => {
    this.setState({ val2: event.target.value });
  };

  add = () => {
    this.setState({ 
      result: parseInt(this.state.val1) + parseInt(this.state.val2)
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello world! The result is: {this.state.result}</h1>
        <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChangeOne} />
        +
        <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChangeTwo} />
        = <br />
        <button onClick={this.add}>Add</button>
        <br/><br/> 
        <button onClick={LogOutButton}>Log Out</button> 
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I know that it is wrong to write this line inside render()

```
<button onClick={LogOutButton}>Log Out</button>
```

However I don't know how to make the LogOutButton component work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add `onLogout` prop to your Logout component and call it when button is clicked.

```
export class LogOutButton extends Component {
  static contextTypes = {
    store: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  };

  handleClick = () => {
    this.context.store.dispatch();
    this.props.onLogout();
  };

  render() {
    return <button type="button" onClick={this.handleClick}>Logout</button>;
  }
}
```

Then in your index.js, pass a function to onLogout prop so that the passed function will be called on button click.

```
onLogoutClick = ()=>{
    window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com';
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello world! The result is: {this.state.result}</h1>
        <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChangeOne} />
        +
        <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChangeTwo} />
        = <br />
        <button onClick={this.add}>Add</button>
        <br/><br/> 
        <LogOutButton onLogout={this.onLogoutClick} />>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. though I am not sure that this will actually LOGOUT the user from the website. If I just go back (after it directs me to google website), I would still be logged in :/

Comment: No. this will not logout the user. that logic you have to write in LogoutButton component.